# Getting data from an insert query?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Im creating a post for an recipe here which has a `recipe_id` and is auto incremented, and on the same page it will return a list of ingredients to add to the recipe

```
def recipeCreate():                                                                                                                           

    if request.method == 'POST':                                  
        userposted = session['user_ID']                           
        title = request.form['title']                             
        prep_time = request.form['preptime']                      
        cook_time = request.form['cooktime']                      
        description = request.form['description']                 
        category = request.form['category']                       
        diet = request.form['diet']                               
        calories = request.form['calories']                       

        c = sq.connection.cursor()                                
        c.execute('INSERT INTO recipe_post (posted_by, name, description, prep_time, cook_time, category, diet, calories)VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',(userposted, title, description, prep_time, cook_time, category, diet, calories))
        sq.connection.commit()                                    
        c.close()                                                 

        return "<h1>Form successfully submitted</h1>"             

    c = sq.connection.cursor()                                    
    result = c.execute('SELECT * FROM Ingredients')               
    data = c.fetchall()                                           

    return render_template('recipe/recipe_form.html', data=data)
```

each ingredient on the ingredient list will be an `<a>` tag that will link to this which will add ingredients for the post

```
@app.route('/recipe/create/add/<recipe_id>/<ingredient_id>/<quantity>')                                                               
def addRecipeIngredient(recipe_id,ingredient_id,quantity):                                                                            
    recipe_id = int(recipe_id)                                                                                                        
    ingredient_id = int(ingredient_id)                                                                                                
    quantity = int(quantity)                                                                                                          
    c = sq.connection.cursor()                                                                                                        

    result = c.execute('INSERT INTO recipe_ingredients(recipe_id,i_id,quantity) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)',(recipe_id,ingredient_id,quantity)) 
    sq.connection.commit()                                                                                                            
    c.close()                                                                                                                         

    INSERT INTO recipe_ingredients(recipe_id,i_id,quantity) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)
```

My issue is that I cannot get the `recipe_id` from `recipeCreate()`, to insert into the recipe ingredient table since it is a post that hasn't been created/queried yet.

I was thinking of inserting the `recipe_post` data first then inserting the ingredient data in the next page but I'd still run into the problem of getting the `recipe_id`.

How can I approach this, is there a way of getting data from an insert query?

Comment: it would be wise to use debugging methods on your programming so that you can track your values where you at.

Answer (score 0):

You can request the last id on the connection using `sq.connection.insert_id()`

If that function is not available, please let me know the name of the sql library you are using.